# Forward iOS Tablet from Linux Desktop to QEMU macOS VM

Tags: linux, osx, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I am running macOS 15 in a [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) virtual machine on a manjaro Linux machine.
Since I want to use it for iOS development/deployment I tried connecting and forwarding an iPad running the latest iPad-OS Version.
Every time I connect the iPad though the virtual machine hangs, and the only way to unfreeze it is to disconnect the iPad again.
I use this command to start the VM:

```
#!/bin/bash

OSK="<OSK>"
VMDIR=$PWD
OVMF=$VMDIR/firmware

qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 6G \
    -machine q35,accel=kvm \
    -smp 4,cores=2 \
    -cpu Penryn,vendor=GenuineIntel,kvm=on,+sse3,+sse4.2,+aes,+xsave,+avx,+xsaveopt,+xsavec,+xgetbv1,+avx2,+bmi2,+smep,+bmi1,+fma,+movbe,+invtsc \
    -device isa-applesmc,osk="$OSK" \
    -smbios type=2 \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file="$OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd" \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file="$OVMF/OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd" \
    -vga qxl \
    -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-output \
    -usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse \
    -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \
    -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 \
    -device ich9-ahci,id=sata \
    -drive id=ESP,if=none,format=qcow2,file=ESP.qcow2 \
    -device ide-hd,bus=sata.2,drive=ESP \
    -drive id=InstallMedia,format=raw,if=none,file=BaseSystem.img \
    -device ide-hd,bus=sata.3,drive=InstallMedia \
    -drive id=SystemDisk,if=none,file=MyDisk.qcow2 \
    -device ide-hd,bus=sata.4,drive=SystemDisk \
    -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x05ac,productid=0x12ab \ # the ipad
```

The last arguments forward the iPad.
Is there something I am missing?

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: One obvious thing to try is to run a Linux distro instead of MacOS in a VM with the same setup, and see if it hangs as well. If it does, it's a qemu problem (so report a bug to the qemu developers). If it doesn't, it's likely a problem in the interaction between MacOS and qemu (which again I'd report as a bug).

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the hint. I tried forwarding the iPad to a Ubuntu VM and it had the exact same issue (except Ubuntu did not recover once the iPad was removed). I will report the bug and update this once I get a response.